# Calling a function in an operator overload?

Tags: c++, class, overloading

I have a class A,

```
class A{

private:
   int num;
public:
   A(int n){ num = n; };
   int getNum(){
       return num;
   }
   A operator+(const A &other){
       int newNum = num + other.getNum();
       return A(newNum);
   };
};
```

Why does `other.getNum()` give an error? I can access variables in other (`other.num`) perfectly fine, but it seems that I can't ever use any of other's functions.

The error I get is something along the lines of

> Invalid arguments: Candidates are int getNum().

I can write `int test = getNum()` but not `int test = other.getNum()`, but I'm almost sure I'm able to call `other.getNum()` somehow.

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: `other` is a constant reference, while `getNum` is not a constant member function.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other is marked const. Therefore, only const methods can be invoked on it. Either make other non-const or make `getNum` a const method. In this case, making `getNum` const would be the way to go.

The reason you can call `getNum` on `this` is because this is not const. Making a method const effectively makes the this pointer const.

Comment: Also operator+ should be const, since it does not change *this.